# jQuery; Setting default options on a per-element basis

Tags: jquery, animation, parameters

Mostly regarding animation;

I have several elements with different animations which may be shown or hidden using their own unique settings; Pop-downs with a slight bounce, menus fading in/out, etc.

Several buttons/widgets/events will hide/show those elements, and I want to avoid having to copy the options in the hide() or show() for each potential call. I also don't want to need to keep track of a list of default options somewhere; I'd like to just set their animation settings as they are initialized, so any scripts later don't need to worry about passing in options.

Is there a way to save the default options for select targets? Something like...

```
$('#foo').setDefaultOptions('hide', {/* New Defaults */});
// or...
$('#foo').hide.defaults = {/* New Defaults */};
```

So calling the below will just use those options without further input:

```
$('#foo').hide(); // Uses those default values set earlier
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.data()` to set the options on the object itself after you've created it.  Then, create your own version of `.hide()` and `.show()` that gets the options from `.data()`.

```
// define custom hide function that retrieves default options
$.fn.myHide = function() {
   this.each(function() {
       var item = $(this);
       item.hide(item.data("animOptions"));
   });
   return this;
}

// set default options once
$("#foo").data("animOptions", {...});


// from then on, just call the method and it uses the object-specific default options
$("#foo").myHide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You could potentially monkeypatch all those methods to allow defaults, however it makes more sense to pass the options yourself.

```
$("#foo").data("hide", { /* defaults here */});

// later on...
var $foo = $("#foo"), options = $foo.data("hide");
$foo.hide(options);
```

if you patch the methods to instead do this part automatically if the data option exists, future developers (or yourself a period of time later) may have a hard time figuring out why calling `.hide()` causes an animation when it shouldn't.